# How to tie a 3 finger swipe to switch workspaces?

Tags: touchpad, workspaces, multi-touch, workspace-switcher

As anyone who has ever used a Mac knows, you can drag left or right on the track pad to switch workspaces. I would love to know if anyone has a way to do this on Ubuntu (14.04) whether this be with tying gestures to key combos or another way.

Thanks for all the answers!